# Distinct SQL selection with percentage condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table like following,

```
portal   partner     location_quality 
38       10060       46
38       10060       46
38       5586        90
4        10060       90
23       11843       10
38       12594       90
38       10438       50
38       10060       90
23       10438       46
36       12660       90
23       12594       50
```

For each pair of portal & partner location_quality ranges from 0 to 100. I want all distinct portal & partner if 90% of location_quality of each pair is greater than 50.

I would like to get all distinct portal & partner pairs if 90% of location_quality is greater than 50. Could somebody help?

Comment: what do you mean 90%.. It will return Everything where location_quality is greater than 50

Comment: 50% of the time it works every time.  So you mean when location_quality is 55.56 or greater?

Comment: For each pair of portal & partner location_quality ranges from 0 to 100. I want all distinct portal & partner if 90% of location_quality of each pair is greater than 50. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @neikusc That's still confusing. Are you saying that location_quality > 50*0.9 or are you talking about 90th percentile? If you don't know the correct term then do include an example.

Comment: @neikusc let me try understand, you wanna take the rows only when the sum of percentages of a group are gratter then 90, like | (row1 + row2 + row3)/3 > 90 | that way the average is gratter then 90.

Comment: Or maybe you just wanna sum the location_quality and se if it was gratter than 90, like ( row1 + row2 + row3 ) > 90

Comment: Let's say for the pair partner = 38 & portal = 10060, location_quality has values {46, 46, 90}. It means only 33.33% of location_quality is greater than 50.

Now I want all pairs that 90% of their location_quality is greater than 50. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think I can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a similar solution as Roger's,

```
SELECT DISTINCT partner, portal from (
    SELECT partner, portal, sum(case when location_quality > 50 then 1 else null end) as cnt_greater_50, CAST(count(*) AS FLOAT) as total_cnt
    FROM tb
    GROUP BY partner, portal
) WHERE cnt_greater_50/total_cnt > 0.9
```

Is there any better idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. group the rows
2. agregad with max
3. filter with having

   ```
   SELECT
    portal,
    partner,
    max(location_quality) as location_quality
   FROM
    table01
   GROUP BY
    portal,
    partner
   HAVING
    max(location_quality) > 50
   ```

Now the solution of your problem

1. count all
2. count when it is above 50
3. Take the porcentage and compare if it is abouve 90%

   ```
   SELECT
    portal,
    partner,
    count(CASE WHEN location_quality > 50 THEN 1 END) * 100 /  count(location_quality ) as percent_above
   FROM
    table01
   GROUP BY
    portal,
    partner
   HAVING
    count(CASE WHEN location_quality > 50 THEN 1 END) * 100 /  count(location_quality ) > 90;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but is this what you mean by 90% *of* location quality?

```
SELECT
 portal,
 partner,
 location_quality
FROM
 table01
GROUP BY
 portal,
 partner
WHERE
 (location_quality * 0.9) > 50
```